# Prove that, if $x(k) \in \mathbb{R}^n $, then $\sum x(k)^T (N^{-1} \sum x(k) x(k)^T)^{-1} x(k) = Nn$

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that, if $x(k) \in \mathbb{R}^n $, then   $\sum_{k=1}^N x(k)^T (\sum_{k=1}^N N^{-1} x(k) x(k)^T)^{-1} x(k) = Nn$, where the sums are over k ranging from 1 to N.
We have N>n. Assume also that $\sum x(k) x(k)^T$ is invertable (full rank).

Comment: I'm not sure that this is true as stated, because $\sum x(k) x(k)^T$ may not be invertible. For example, if n =3 and we have just one vector x(1), then $x(1)x(1)^T$ is a 3 by 3 matrix of rank 1, and thus not invertible. Do you have any additional preconditions?

Comment: I just edited the question. You can assume N > n

Comment: What if all the $x(k)$ are zero, for example? This is just *one* example when the result is non invertible.

Comment: Assume a situation where the weighting matrix is invertable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define: $X = \begin{bmatrix} x(1)^T \dots x(N)^T \end{bmatrix} ^T$

Then the sum above can be written as

$ N \cdot \text{trace}(X^T (XX^T)^{-1} X)$ = $N \cdot \text{rank}(X)$

Comment: Neat. :-) I think, the N on both sides of the equation is a bit superfluous.

Comment: N is useful for numerical computations. Usually we need such normalization when N is large, other wise we will end up with very large entries in $XX^T$. However, it is has no role in the proof I agree.